# Changing colors in a scatterplot using Matplotlib with python

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, scatter-plot

I am currently taking a Matplotlib class. I was given an image to create the image as a 3D subplot 4 times at 4 different angles. It's a linear plot. As the data changes the plots change colors. As it's an image, I'm not certain where the actual changes start. I don't want an exact answer, just an explanation of how this would work. I have found many methods for doing this for a small list but this has 75 data points and I can't seem to do it without adding 75 entries.
I've also tried to understand cmap but I am confused on it as well.
Also, it needs to done without Seaborn.
[This is part of the photo.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkCEz.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am finding your question a little bit hard to understand. What I think you need is a function to map the input x/y argument onto a colour in your chosen colour map. See the below example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot


def number_to_colour(number, total_number):
    return plt.cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0,1.,total_number))[list(number)]


x = np.arange(12)
y = x*-3.
z = x


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(x, y, z, c=number_to_colour(x, len(x)))
plt.show()
```

`plt.cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0,1.,total_number))` creates an array of colours of length `total_number` evenly spaced spaced across the colour map (in this case `rainbow`). Modifying the indexing of this array (or changing np.linspace to another function with the desired scaling), should give you the colour scaling that you need.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand how that works except for this line: 

return plt.cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0,1.,12))[list(number)]

I assume plt.cm.rainbow is the path to the colormaps. But why the 12 decimals created by linespace?

Comment: Also, this is a 3D plot so Z needs to be included as well.

Comment: Yes 'rainbow' is the colourmap, this may be replaced by any of the matplotlib colourmaps.   `plt.cm.rainbow()` will generate colours from numbers between 0 and 1 (that give the extrema of the colourmap spectrum). 

`plt.cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0,1.,12))`, therefore, is an array of 12 different colours that spans the colourmap 'rainbow'.